# Como obtener fecha de input date y valor seleccionado en select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

¿Cómo puedo pasar de *mi vista* a *mi controlador* una fecha seleccionada en un *input type date* y el valor seleccionado de un `select`? ¿Podría pasarlo por medio del `button_to`? ¿De qué manera se conseguiría esto?

Lo que tengo realizado en la vista es lo siguiente:

```
   <p>Prestador:</p>
   <%= collection_select(:provider, :id_persona, Provider.order(:id), :id, :fullname) %>
   <br>
   <input id="date" type="date" value="today()">
   <br>
   <td class="pull-right"><%=  button_to "Ver horarios", turnos_path %></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando una forma en tu vista, por ejemplo con `form_for` (asumiendo que has creado el objeto `@provider` en tu controlador y que tienes las rutas adecuadas en *config/routes.rb*):

```
<% form_for @provider do |f| %>
  <p>Prestador:</p>
  <%= collection_select(:provider, :id_persona, Provider.order(:id), :id, :fullname) %>
  <br>
  <input name="date" id="date" type="date" value="today()">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
<% end %>
```

En tu controlador puedes obtener la información de la forma a través del objeto `params`; por ejemplo, si quieres obtener el valor del `select`:

```
params[:provider][:id_persona]
```

Y para la fecha:

```
params[:date]
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre los *helpers* para formas en las [guías de *Rails*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) para una mejor comprensión del tema.

---

> Lo que deseo hacer es que a partir de esa fecha y provider que
>   selecciono, el controlador me ejecute un procedure de mi base de datos
>   y me devuelva los datos que trajo en la vista

Puedes utilizar una forma normal, proporcionando la ruta directamente (o el *helper* asociado) la cual puedes obtener a través de comando `rails routes`; por ejemplo:

```
<form method="post" action="<%= mi_ruta_path %>">
  <p>Prestador:</p>
  <%= select_tag 'provider', options_from_collection_for_select(Provider.order(:id), :id, :fullname) %>
  <br>
  <input name="date" id="date" type="date" value="today()">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Para leer los valores en tu controlador utilizarías el mismo objeto `params`, solo ajustando al nombre dado en el `select`:

```
params[:provider]
params[:date]
```

Comment: Claro lo que pasa que no tengo un modelo generado para eso entonces no me funciona. Lo que deseo hacer es que a partir de esa fecha y provider que selecciono, el controlador me ejecute un procedure de mi base de datos y me devuelva los datos que trajo en la vista

Comment: @francofernandez He añadido a la respuesta una alternativa para el escenario que planteas, espero te sirva.

Comment: Me ha servido de mucha ayuda. Tengo otra duda, si yo deseo enviar el action a mi show del controlador para que me realice unas acciones y muestre unos datos, como deberia llamarlo? porque en el action pongo lo siguiente: <form method="get" action="<%= turnos_path %>"> y me recarga la pagina con las variables en la url que yo le paso en el form

Comment: @francofernandez La acción en el controlador la llamas utilizando la ruta adecuada, es decir, la _url_  y el método varían dependiendo cómo hayas configurado estas rutas en _config/routes.rb_.

Comment: Es decir, si en el controlador de 'turnos' defino un metodo llamado 'filtro', en mi archivo routes.rb deberia definir: post 'turnos/filtro', as: 'turnos_filtro' ?

Comment: @francofernandez Así es, aunque la parte `as: turnos_filtro` solo se necesita para nombrar el _helper_ que genera la ruta; ejecuta el comando `rails routes` y podrás ver esta información.

Comment: Lo definí en mi routes.rb asi: get 'turnos/mostrar_turnos', as: 'mostrar_turnos'. Y el action de mi view index asi: action="<%= mostrar_turnos_url %>". Me direcciona bien a la url pero me larga el siguiente error: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass. Mi view mostrar_turnos.html.erb deberia mostrar los datos de una consulta que realizo en mi metodo mostrar_turnos de mi controlador de turnos

Comment: @francofernandez Tienes una variable que no está inicializando correctamente, te recomiendo abrir una nueva pregunta donde muestres el error y el código relacionado, así será más sencillo ver donde está el error y darte una respuesta completa.

Comment: Ahi te dejo el enlace de la pregunta reformulada por si encuentras algo que me puedas ayudar. Muchas gracias. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/323660/problema-routes-ruby

Comment: Hola @Gerry , alguna idea para esto? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/325314/sumar-dos-variables-tipo-time-ruby