# Sumar dos variables tipo time Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Como puedo sumar dos variables tipo time? 
Tengo una variable:

```
@i = prueba.schedule.hs_start.strftime("%H:%M")
```

> que me da como resultado 09:00

y tengo otra variable:

```
<%= @d = prueba.duration_turn.strftime("%H:%M") %>
```

> que me da como resultado 00:15

Lo que necesito es sumar `@i + @d` y me de como resultado 09:15
Alguna solucion?

Comment: He revertido tus últimos cambios en la pregunta, ya que vi que hiciste la pregunta aparte (lo cual es lo correcto), así esta pregunta que enfocada en el problema de las variables tipo time solamente. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dando el supuesto que tienes dos variables de tiempo, una con 9:00 y otra con 0:15

```
irb(main):110:0> hs_start = Time.new(2020, 1, 30, 9, 0)
=> 2020-01-30 09:00:00 +1300
irb(main):111:0> duration_turn = Time.new(2020, 1, 30, 0, 15)
=> 2020-01-30 00:15:00 +1300
```

puedes saber las horas y minutos de `duration_turn` con los métodos [`.hour`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-hour) y [`.min`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-min), que te retornará un integer con su valor.

```
irb(main):112:0> duration_turn.hour
=> 0
irb(main):113:0> duration_turn.min
=> 15
```

a estos integers se les puede encadenar los métodos [`.hours`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-hours) y [`.minutes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-minutes) (solo en rails), que te retornarán un objeto de tipo [`ActiveSupport::Duration`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html), el cual representa el equivalente en segundos del tiempo indicado en el integer.

```
[4] pry(main)> duration_turn.hour.hours
=> 0 seconds
[5] pry(main)> duration_turn.min.minutes
=> 900 seconds
```

El beneficio de `ActiveSupport::Duration`, es que te permite sumar estos segundos a tu tiempo original, para conseguir el resultado que esperas.

```
irb(main):115:0> total = hs_start + duration_turn.hour.hours + duration_turn.min.minutes
=> 2020-01-30 09:15:00 +1300
irb(main):116:0> total.strftime("%H:%M")
=> "09:15"
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias !! Me ha funcionado de maravilla !! Ahora si yo quiero meter dentro de un while comparando total con hs_end como seria? En el codigo te edito y agrego lo que realice que no me funciona

Comment: Hay alguna posibilidad de sumar ademas los segundos de la variable 'duration_turn'?

Comment: Está todo en la doc de las clases que detallé en la respuesta. Checa https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-sec y https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-seconds